# How can I number theorems in introduction without section counter and later with it?

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm, ntheorem

I would like to have my theorems numbered in the following way.

> Theorem 1. Blah-blah
>
> Theorem 2. More blah-blah
>
> Section 1.
>
> Theorem 1.1. Special blah
>
> Theorem 1.2. More special blah
>
> Section 2
>
> Theorem 2.1. Another special blah

and so on, preferably using the `amsmath` package. I've been struggling for a while with this, can anyone suggest a simple solution? I would also like to be able to `\label` and `\ref` all theorems.

Comment: What is your document class? Is your introduction an unnumbered section, chapter or whatever else?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have both [tag:amsthm] and [tag:ntheorem]; which of the two packages are you using in your document?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @egreg I use amsthm and optionally I can use any other packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple solution. Define your structures without their counters being subordinate to the section counter and just *before* the first `\section` use `\numberwithin` from the `amsmath` (or `\counterwithin` from the `chngcntr` package) package to add the `section` counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}
Some cross-references: \ref{a}, \ref{b}, \ref{c}, \ref{d}, \ref{e}, and \ref{f}.
\begin{thm}\label{a}
test theorem in the introduction
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}\label{b}
test lemma in the introduction
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}\label{c}
test theorem in the introduction
\end{thm}

\numberwithin{thm}{section}
\section{A test numbered section}

\begin{lem}\label{d}
test lemma in a numbered section
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}\label{e}
test theorem in a numbered section
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}\label{f}
test theorem in the introduction
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, such a simple solution and good to know command, thx!

Answer (score 5):

You won't have scores of theorems in your introduction, so a soft approach could be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{thm*}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}

In this paper we'll prove the following result.

\begin{thm*}
All numbers are odd.
\end{thm*}

This striking result has several consequences.


\section{Preliminary results}

Here is the most useful lemma.

\begin{lem}
The number $1$ is even.
\end{lem}

\begin{proof}
Everybody can see it.
\end{proof}

Here is a first consequence.

\begin{thm}
All prime numbers are odd.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
Since $2=1+1$, $2$ is odd.
\end{proof}

\section{The main result}

We are now ready to prove our main result.

\begin{thm}
All numbers are odd.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
Since $0$ is obviously even, $1$ is odd. But $1$ is even, so also
$0$ is odd. A number $n>1$ is a product of primes, hence odd.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can define a generic environment for theorems in the introduction:

```
\newcommand{\introthmname}{}
\newtheorem*{introthminn}{\introthmname}

\newenvironment{introthm}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\introthmname}{#1}\begin{introthminn}}
  {\end{introthminn}}
```

and then state your theorems in the introduction as

```
\begin{introthm}{Lemma}
The number $1$ is even.
\end{introthm}

\begin{introthm}{Theorem}
All numbers are odd.
\end{introthm}
```

Here's a version that numbers the statements in the introduction and also swaps the numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\newcommand{\introthmname}{}
\newtheorem{introthminn}{\introthmname}
\newenvironment{introthm}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\introthmname}{#1}\begin{introthminn}}
  {\end{introthminn}}

\swapnumbers

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}

In this paper we'll prove the following result.

\begin{introthm}{Theorem}\label{thm:main}
All numbers are odd.
\end{introthm}

This striking result has several consequences.


\section{Preliminary results}

Here's the most useful lemma.

\begin{lem}
The number $1$ is even.
\end{lem}

\begin{proof}
Everybody can see it.
\end{proof}

Here's a first consequence.

\begin{thm}
All prime numbers are odd.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
Since $2=1+1$, $2$ is odd.
\end{proof}

\section{The main result}

We are now ready to prove our main result, already stated as 
Theorem~\ref{thm:main} in the introduction.

\begin{thm}
All numbers are odd.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
Since $0$ is obviously even, $1$ is odd. But $1$ is even, so also
$0$ is odd. A number $n>1$ is a product of primes, hence odd.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I suppose introducing an introthm is the simplest solution, probably I will go with this unless anyone has some even simpler method.

Comment: Actually, I have just realized that this doesn't work for me because I want to be able to label and reference these theorems.

Comment: @domotorp If they have no number, how can you reference them?

Comment: They have. In the intro they are numbered without section and after I would like them numbered with section, as in the example given in my question.

Comment: @domotorp They aren't numbered in my version; however, I'll add one with numbers as you wish.

Comment: Dear egreg, thank you for helping me. What I would need is exactly what I have at the beginning of my question, numbers that come after the theorem and then being able to label them. Your example gives numbers before the theorems.

Comment: @domotorp Add `\swapnumbers` after `\usepackage{amsthm}`.

Comment: I am sorry but it does not seem like we would understand each other. I would like exactly what I wrote at the beginning of my question.

Comment: @domotorp According to the documentation, this should work; but it doesn't. Add `\swapnumbers` at the end of the preamble, just before `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that does what you want, I think. It uses the `titlesec` package, for it allows different formatting for numbered and unnumbered sections,  and `etoolbox` to easily define a suitable boolean, `numsect' that I set to true for numbered section, and false for the unnumbered, thanks to titlesec. The I redefine the formatting of the theorem label differently, according to the valeue of this boolean.

As the theorem counter is not reset at a new unnumbered section, I had to incorporate it in the unnumbered section formatting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox, chngcntr} %
\newbool{numsect}
\titleformat{name = \section}[hang]{\global\booltrue{numsect}\Large\bfseries}{\arabic{section}.}{0.5em} {}
\titleformat{name = \section, numberless}[hang]{\setcounter{thm}{0}\global\boolfalse{numsect}\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}%
```

%
    \renewcommand\thethm{\ifbool{numsect}{\thesection.\arabic{thm}}{\arabic{thm}}}%

```
\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}

In this paper we'll prove the following result.

\begin{thm}
All numbers are odd.
\end{thm}

This striking result has several consequences.

\section{Preliminary results}

Here is the most useful lemma.

\begin{lem}
The number $1$ is even.
\end{lem}

\begin{proof}
Everybody can see it.
\end{proof}

Here is a first consequence.

\begin{thm}
All prime numbers are odd.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
Since $2=1+1$, $2$ is odd.
\end{proof}

\section{The main result}

We are now ready to prove our main result. \

\begin{thm}
All numbers are odd.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
Since $0$ is obviously even, $1$ is odd. But $1$ is even, so also
$0$ is odd. A number $n>1$ is a product of primes, hence odd.
\end{proof}

\section*{Conclusion}

\begin{thm}
Even even numbers are odd.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]